# Use of で particle over を

Tags: particle-で

## English

I have heard following sentence in video.

> さっきの手紙に何で書いてあったかな。

I’m not able to understand, why で has been used.

Why not following statement is correct?

> さっきの手紙になにを書いてあったかな。

## 日本語

ビデオで以下の文を聞きました。

> 文：さっきの手紙に何で書いてあったかな。

「で」はどうして使っているのかわかりません。

以下の文は正しいですか？

> さっきの手紙になにを書いてあったかな。

Comment: I think what you heard was 何て, not 何で... and... are you sure it said あったな, not あったかな or あったの?

Comment: Even if it is 何て ,  why て is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence should be:

> さっきの手紙に[何]{なん}**て**書いてあったかな。

The 「て」 is a colloquial variant of the quotative particle 「と」.

> て
>   〘格助・副助・終助〙
>   「って」が「ん」で終わる語に続くときの形。⇒って
>   「今何**て**言った？（格助）」
>   (from 明鏡国語辞典)

「て」 is used instead of 「って」 when attached to a word ending with ん.

Your sentence can be rephrased as:

> さっきの手紙に[何]{なん}**と**書いてあったかな。

---

> さっきの手紙になに**を**書いてあったかな。

doesn't sound natural. You could instead say it as:

> さっきの手紙に[何]{なに}**が**書いてあったかな。

書いてあった means "was written (there)", so probably this is why 何が sounds natural and 何を sounds unnatural here.